# How to configure ingress to a service in kubernetes hosted on jelastic?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, jelastic

Here's the thing. I installed a kubernetes cluster on my jelastic account like this:

[image]

Then, I wanted to expose a service to the outside of the cluster. The HelloWorld is working out-of-the-box on the cluster, so I thought I could transform it to my needs easily. Upon cluster installation, browsing

```
my-helloworld-test.my-jelastic-provider.com
```

works perfectly fine, i.e. I see the hello world html page with styling.

Now, in my future use-cases, I will want to access my services through

```
my-helloworld-test.my-jelastic-provider.com/hello
```

or

```
hello.my-helloworld-test.my-jelastic-provider.com
```

i.e. I'd like to setup a path for my service or a subdomain. I gathered I need to define an Ingress to make that happen. I've changed the `hello-kubernetes` service configuration to this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: hello-kubernetes
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
```

### Path to service

I tried following ingress configuration to define a path to my service:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: helloworld
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /hello
            backend:
              serviceName: hello-kubernetes
              servicePort: 80
```

The goal is that browsing

```
my-helloworld-test.my-jelastic-provider.com/hello
```

displays the pre-deployed helloworld application, instead of

```
my-helloworld-test.my-jelastic-provider.com
```

I could write the helloworld application in such a way that its base url be `/hello`, but I learned from several blogs that it is possible to let that happen with kubernetes annotations. In particular, it seems like annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` would help, but I was not able to make it happen completely. Indeed, the above configuration shows me the helloworld application when I browse the `/hello` path, but unstyled:

[image]

How can I make the styling happen?

### Subdomain to service

Another sexy possibility for that service would be to be displayed upon browsing

```
hello.my-helloworld-test.my-jelastic-provider.com
```

i.e. as a subdomain of my jelastic environment. I've tried this configuration without success:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - host: hello.my-helloworld-test.my-jelastic-provider.com
            path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: hello-kubernetes
              servicePort: 80
```

What do I need to do to my jelastic environment so that the above host be browsable and exhibits the helloworld application?

### Kubernetes configuration

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.6", GitCommit:"7015f71e75f670eb9e7ebd4b5749639d42e20079", GitTreeState:"archive", BuildDate:"2019-11-19T09:00:01Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Co
mpiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.6", GitCommit:"7015f71e75f670eb9e7ebd4b5749639d42e20079", GitTreeState:"archive", BuildDate:"2019-11-19T08:45:41Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Co
mpiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

on jelastic v.5.7.

Comment: What kubernetes version are you using? Do you have any firewall rules? To make sure, you are trying to use ClusterIP with Ingress?

Comment: I've reformulated my question and added my kubernetes configuration details. I have no firewall rules and I am trying to use `ClusterIP` with Ingress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there are 2 separate issues atm

1. Are you sure that domain
   hello.my-helloworld-test.my-jelastic-provider.com is following to a
   correct IP? It is possible to add custom subdomains to the
   environment, then use them for ingress rules, but that option
   (custom subdomains) is now available through the [API](https://docs.jelastic.com/api/#!/api/environment.Binder-method-AddDomains) only
2. Incorrect annotation argument for nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target, if you use nginx ingress controller try this one

```html
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: helloworld
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /hello(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: hello-kubernetes
              servicePort: 80
```

**UPD:** 
We have additionally checked the issue together with Laurent Michel and discovered that problem was caused by absolute URIs in application so rewrite was not applied to CSS/images. Simplest solution - apply two ingress rules with different annotations (one with rewrite and one without). More advanced and correct way to go - shift such applications to separate subdomains so URIs could remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply. However, the ingress configuration you propose does not work for me. I still end up with the same styleless html page.

Comment: I've tested your first proposal for the subdomain. I installed [this manifest](https://github.com/shopozor/k8s-playground/blob/master/jenkins/addSubdomain.jps) and then used the ingress I posted in my question with the host name. I get a 502 server response when I browse `hello.my-helloworld-test.my-jelastic-provider.com`.